# 2D TicTacToe with computer side random number generator

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

My code only prints empty spaces instead of prompting each time to enter a row and column number and see if the space is empty. I have to generate random numbers for computer player but not sure if I did it right

```
import java.util.*;
public class TicTacToe
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  int row, column;
  char player = 'X';
  char[][] board = new char[3][3];
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<3;++j){
        board[i][j] = ' ';
     }
     }   
     while(!checkWin(board,'O')==true)
     {
        computerPlay(board);
        displayBoard(board);
        if(checkWin(board,'X'))
        {
           System.out.println("Computer Wins");
           System.exit(0);
        }
        if(checkTie(board))
        {
           System.out.println("Tie game");
           System.exit(0);
        }
        playerPlay(board);
        displayBoard(board);
        if(checkWin(board,'O'))
        {
           System.out.println("Player Wins");
           System.exit(0);
        }
        if(checkTie(board))
        {
           System.out.println("Tie game");
           System.exit(0);
        }
     }
  }

   // Prompt the user for row & column index. Continue asking 
  // until an empty cell is selected. set the cell to 'O'
  public static void playerPlay(char[][] board)
  { 
  int row, column;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  while(checkTie(board)!= true)
  {

     System.out.println("Enter a row and column (0, 1, or 2); for player 
:");
     row = in.nextInt();
     column = in.nextInt();
  }
 }
 // Check by row, column, and diagonals
 public static boolean checkWin(char[][] board,char ch)
 {
  if (  board[0][0] == 'O' && board[0][1] == 'O' && board[0][2] == 'O' || // 
  1st row
        board[1][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[1][2] == 'O' || // 
   2nd row
        board[2][0] == 'O' && board[2][1] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O' || // 
   3rd row
        board[0][0] == 'O' && board[1][0] == 'O' && board[2][0] == 'O' || // 
   1st col.
        board[0][1] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][1] == 'O' || // 
  2nd col.
        board[0][2] == 'O' && board[1][2] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O' || // 
  3rd col.
        board[0][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O' || // 
  Diagonal          \ 
        board[2][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[0][2] == 'O') //   
   Diagonal      /
   {
     return true;
   }
   else {

     return false;
   }
}

 // check for tie. If there no empty cells, then it is a tie
 public static boolean checkTie(char[][] board)
 {
  for (int i = 0; i< board.length; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
        if (board[i][j] != 'O' && board[i][j] != 'X') {
           return true;
        }
     }
   }
  return false;
 }
// Display the board
 public static void displayBoard(char[][] board)
 {
  System.out.println(board[0][0] + " | " + board[0][1] + " | " + board[0][2] 
 + "\n---------");
  System.out.println(board[1][0] + " | " + board[1][1] + " | " + board[1][2] 
 + "\n---------");
  System.out.println(board[2][0] + " | " + board[2][1] + " | " + board[2][2] 
 + "\n");
}
 // Continue generating random values for row and col until an 
 // empty cell selected. Set the cell to 'X'
 public static void computerPlay(char[][]board)
 {
  while(checkTie(board)!= true)
  {
     for (int i=0; i<board.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<board.length; j++){
           board[i][j] = (char)(Math.random()*10);

        }

     }

  }

 }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `checkTie` function returns `true` if any board value is empty (strictly, not "X" or "O"). The `computerPlay` function only proceeds if the return value of `checkTie` is `false`. The logic of one of these (but not both) should be inverted. I would recommend changing the name of the isTied function to avoid confusion, and inverting the logic in that function. Here's my recommendation (which also replaces the `while` with an `if`, because it should only be run once):

```
 public static boolean isTied(char[][] board)
 {
  for (int i = 0; i< board.length; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
        if (board[i][j] != 'O' && board[i][j] != 'X') {
           return false;
        }
     }
   }
  return true;
 }
 ...
 public static void computerPlay(char[][]board)
 {
  if(!isTied(board))
  {
     for (int i=0; i<board.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<board.length; j++){
           board[i][j] = (char)(Math.random()*10);
        }
     }
  }
 }
```